# SwiftUI - CoreData one too many relationship append array

Tags: core-data, swiftui

So I'm using CoreData and wish to append an array of activities. The issue is, it will only append one/the latest entry within the view model array. This works as a one too many relationship.

```
 let activity = Activity(context: self.moc)
activity.trip = Trip(context: self.moc)
 activity.trip?.destinationName = destinationName
 
for activityIndex in flightOverViewModel.selectedActivites {
  let ind = Activity()
  ind.title = activityIndex.title
  ind.name = activityIndex.name
  ind.longitude = activityIndex.longitude
  ind.latitude = activityIndex.latitude
}
  try? self.moc.save()
```

I've tried `activity.trip?.activitiesArray.append(ind)` but get an error saying *'Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'activitiesArray' is a get-only property'*.

Any ideas on how I can index and append each value in flightOverViewModel.selectedActivites array to CoreData?

Thank you.